# Getting "१:१३:१२" type of duration on server. Is there any way to change it to "01:13:12"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, duration

I am getting duration in the wrong format(i.e. **१:१३:१२**) with request. When I trying to insert in Postgres database it's showing **DateTimeParseError** which is expected.

Can we change this(**१:१३:१२**) type of duration in actual duration format like this(**01:13:12**) HH:MM:SS on the server side?

Comment: You should probably try to use to switch the locale if you need to print the date in a human readable format. Else, why don't you save the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Method 1 - short dirty fix - calculate difference between your set of number characters and latin number characters and replace them. Then just fill missing "0"s 
See code below (it works for your example, but I don't make any validation of input string, it's up to you)

```js
var str = "१:१३:१२";

var offset = "१".charCodeAt(0) - "1".charCodeAt(0);

// replace everything but ":"
var result = str.replace(/[^:]/g, function(el){
  return String.fromCharCode(el.charCodeAt(0) - offset);
})

console.log(result);

result = result.split(":").map(el=>el.length === 2? el: "0" + el).join(":");
console.log(result);
```

Method 2 - recommended - use locales when you create duration string, for example: if you have access to `Data` object of your duration you can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) and get string with latin numbering system: `"nu-latin"` part in locale string. 
Note: if you use some library to create duration there's propably some way to set locale

```js
var date = new Date()

logLocaleDate("en-u-nu-deva-hc-h24")
logLocaleDate("en-u-nu-latin-hc-h24")

function logLocaleDate(locale){
  var res = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second:"2-digit"}).format(date))

  console.log(res);
}
```